# Is sexágéní horae an appropriate translation of minute/minuto?

Tags: translation-check

My Spanish-English dictionary translates minute/minuto as punctum temporis, which makes sense in some usages of the words, but not makes sense when speaking of the units, thus is sexágéní horae an appropriate translation of the term?

Answer (score 3):

No, because *sexageni* is a distributive number and means “sixty each.” *Pater filiis suis denarios sexagenos dono dedit* = The father gave his sons sixty denars each (*denarios sexaginta* would be sixty in all).

A sixteeth is *sexagesima (pars)*, and the sixteeth part of an hour would therefore be *sexagesima (pars) (unius) horae*.

That's not what it is called, though. The usual term is ***minuta*** (f), which might stand for *hora minuta* or (which seems more plausible to me) *horae pars minuta* (with an implied *prima*, as a once again diminished minute is a *pars minuta secunda*). This term is very common in scientific Latin. I believe it goes back to the Middle Ages, or even to the Late Latin period, as you can even read the term *minuta* for a sixteeth subdivision – in the conext of astronomical calculations, which he did not fancy – in St. Augustine (*De diversis quaestionibus* 1, 45 (*Adversus mathematicos*)):

> motum autem coaeli per unam horam fieri in quindecim partibus, ut tanta mora quindecim partes oriantur, quantam tenet una hora. Quae partes singulae sexaginta minutas habere dicuntur.

(OK, I'm not a *mathematicus*, but in my book that's 15 × 60 = 900 minutes per hour? Never mind that, though – this is the fourth century. In post-renaissance scientific Latin a *minuta* is definitely the familiar minute.)

That some dictionaries balk at this expression is due to the fact that it is not classical. The ancient Romans did not speak of *minutis* and seem not to have worked with 60th divisions of the hour – even when using our familiar hour (technically called an equinoctial hour), which they only did in a scientific context. Instead they worked with various fractions as they saw fit. You can see this, for example, in Pliny's descriptions of various geographical parallels (Naturalis Historia 6, 39):

> … dies autem noxque maxima XIIII horarum aequinoctialium est accedente bis quinta parte unius horae.
> Longissimus dies est aequinoctialium horarum XIIII atque dimidiae cum tricesima unius horae.
> Longissimus dies habet aequinoctiales horas XIIII et tertias duas unius horae.
>
> … the longest day and night is 14 equinoctial hours plus two fifths of one hour (= 14:24).
> The longest day is 14 and a half equinoctial hours and one thirteeth of one hour (= 14:32)
> The longest day has 14 equinoctial hours and two thirds of one hour (= 14:40).

Answer (score 1):

My Latin-English dictionary (Traupman) gives *minuta* for minute, probably short for *divisio minuta horae*, a small division of the hour. Second is *secunda*, the 2nd division, i.e., the division of the division.

Comment: The full phrases I've heard are *pars minuta* & *pars minuta secunda*, which are mostly shortened to what you cite.